# Scheduling one task per gpu on multiple nodes

Tags: gpu, slurm

I am trying to schedule 8 tasks on two separate nodes.
Each node has 4 GPUs and I want to assign one per tasks.

The following code works fine on 1 node and 4 GPUS:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#SBATCH --time 24:00:00
#SBATCH --partition=X

#SBATCH --mem=96G               # RAM per node
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=12       # number of CPUs per process

#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:4

srun --gres=gpu:1 --ntasks=1 --exclusive p.py Job.num_workers=4 Job.worker_id=1 &
srun --gres=gpu:1 --ntasks=1 --exclusive p.py Job.num_workers=4 Job.worker_id=2 &
srun --gres=gpu:1 --ntasks=1 --exclusive p.py Job.num_workers=4 Job.worker_id=3 &
srun --gres=gpu:1 --ntasks=1 --exclusive p.py Job.num_workers=4 Job.worker_id=4 &

echo "Start!"
wait
echo "Done!"
```

But if I try to use 2 nodes and 4 more GPUS like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#SBATCH --mail-type=ALL
#SBATCH --time 24:00:00
#SBATCH --partition=X

#SBATCH --mem=96G               # RAM per node
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=12       # number of CPUs per process

#SBATCH --nodes=2
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:4

srun --gres=gpu:1 --ntasks=1 --exclusive p.py Job.num_workers=8 Job.worker_id=1 &
srun --gres=gpu:1 --ntasks=1 --exclusive p.py Job.num_workers=8 Job.worker_id=2 &
srun --gres=gpu:1 --ntasks=1 --exclusive p.py Job.num_workers=8 Job.worker_id=3 &
srun --gres=gpu:1 --ntasks=1 --exclusive p.py Job.num_workers=8 Job.worker_id=4 &
srun --gres=gpu:1 --ntasks=1 --exclusive p.py Job.num_workers=8 Job.worker_id=5 &
srun --gres=gpu:1 --ntasks=1 --exclusive p.py Job.num_workers=8 Job.worker_id=6 &
srun --gres=gpu:1 --ntasks=1 --exclusive p.py Job.num_workers=8 Job.worker_id=7 &
srun --gres=gpu:1 --ntasks=1 --exclusive p.py Job.num_workers=8 Job.worker_id=8 &

echo "Start!"
wait
echo "Done!"
```

I get repeated messages saying:

```
srun: Warning: can't run 1 processes on 2 nodes, setting nnodes to 1
```

I would like to understand, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You said you want to use two nodes (`#SBATCH --nodes=2`), then in the `srun` command, you are asking for one task (`--ntasks=1`) and `srun` is also inheriting the parent configuration of two nodes. And then, srun complains that it cannot fulfill this request: one task in two nodes. Just tell `srun` that you want to use a single node (`--nodes=1`).

Comment: You are absolutely right, I did not think about that.

Answer (score 0):

As @poshi suggested, the problem is that the srun commands are inheriting the `--nodes=2` flag. It is enough to add `--nodes=1` to the srun commands to solve the issue:

```
#SBATCH --partition=boosterX

#SBATCH --mem=96GG               # RAM per node
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=12       # number of CPUs per process

#SBATCH --nodes=2
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:4

srun --gres=gpu:1 --ntasks=1 --nodes=1 --exclusive p.py Job.num_workers=8 Job.worker_id=1 &
srun --gres=gpu:1 --ntasks=1 --nodes=1 --exclusive p.py Job.num_workers=8 Job.worker_id=2 &
srun --gres=gpu:1 --ntasks=1 --nodes=1 --exclusive p.py Job.num_workers=8 Job.worker_id=3 &
srun --gres=gpu:1 --ntasks=1 --nodes=1 --exclusive p.py Job.num_workers=8 Job.worker_id=4 &
srun --gres=gpu:1 --ntasks=1 --nodes=1 --exclusive p.py Job.num_workers=8 Job.worker_id=5 &
srun --gres=gpu:1 --ntasks=1 --nodes=1 --exclusive p.py Job.num_workers=8 Job.worker_id=6 &
srun --gres=gpu:1 --ntasks=1 --nodes=1 --exclusive p.py Job.num_workers=8 Job.worker_id=7 &
srun --gres=gpu:1 --ntasks=1 --nodes=1 --exclusive p.py Job.num_workers=8 Job.worker_id=8 &

echo "Start"
wait
echo "Done!"
```